# Is it posible to use styled components library on angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, styled-components

I just wanna make sure if anybody use styled-components on angularjs, i use angulajs 1.7 that updated to component based, so please help me if you already implement it on your angularjs
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Comment: I'm not that familiar with styled components but they are used to create components as name suggest, in AngularJS you have templates. I think that make no sens to have it in AngularJS application, with AngularJS you can use ngStyle to create style, so there is no need for another library.